Jaspersoft Report Library and Jaspersoft Studio community edition for commercial use
I'm integrating third-party libraries such as Jaspersoft Report Library 7.0 and Jaspersoft Studio 7.0.0 into a Java application to generate reports for a client application. The workflow involves creating jrxml files in Jaspersoft Studio, which are then used in the application for one-time report generation.
We're not using advanced features like Jaspersoft Studio Pro or JasperReport Server. However, there seems to be no clear documentation on the licensing terms since the release of Jaspersoft 7.0. I'm trying to understand if this setup complies with the LGPL 3.0 license, particularly regarding commercial use and distribution of the reports.
Given the uncertainty, should we consider moving to BIRT or another reporting tool that might have clearer licensing terms for commercial use in client applications?
I tried to find it in jaspersoft documentation and forum but didn't find any information related to latest version.
Can anyone clarify the licensing implications in this scenario?

Can you provide a link to the relevant repositories of Jaspersoft?

I can't find a repo per se but the download page is pretty clear as to the licensing - "License GNU Library or Lesser General Public License version 3.0 (LGPLv3)"

Jaspersoft report library is open source link  but the jaspersoft studio repo was made private recently and also changed license  link

I'm sorry this question's had no bites.  I tried this morning, and realised I'm not sure why you're asking about LGPL.  Are you planning on releasing your Java application, and if so, are you planning on releasing it under LGPL?  If so, is this due to the use of third-party LGPL code in it, or is it just a personal decision?  If I've got the wrong end of the stick, could you clarify your plans a bit?
